# Adding custom job property to Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to add a new mandatory job property to capture the some custom fields in the jenkins job. I searched in the plugins list but couldn't find any relevant plugin that solves the issue. Is there any plugin to solve this ? (Note: Extra columns plugin doesn't solve my usecase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A freestyle job can be configured to build with parameters. See: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

You can configure the parameter type (string, boolean, drop down etc), give a description of the parameter and a default value. The string parameters can include validation rules:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Validating+String+Parameter+Plugin

Though this only warns when the current parameter value does not meet the regex validation rule, it doesn't prevent the build from being submitted. If submitted in this state, however, the build will fail.

From a quick google, it appears this doesn't work for pipeline jobs, See the last comment on the plugin page url above from **Miguelángel Fernández**:

*If you look at the implementation of class ValidatingStringParameterValue you'll see that it overrides the implementation of public BuildWrapper createBuildWrapper(AbstractBuild build) in a way that aborts if the string is invalid. This will only work on Freestyle jobs and other job types extending AbstractBuild. I'm afraid this does not apply to pipeline jobs. Maybe in your prior project you used freestyle jobs.*

An alternative for freestyle jobs is to do in job validation before initiating any build steps using the 'Prepare an environment for the run' from:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

You would need to write groovy to check the parameters submitted and abort the build at this point if the values aren't suitable. Something like:

```
def validateString = binding.variables.get('testParam')

if (!binding.variables.get('testParam').matches('\\d+')) {
   println "failure of parameter validation - does not match regex"
   throw new InterruptedException()
} else {
   println "Validation passed carry on with build"
}
```

This doesn't work on pipeline builds - as the plugin is quote:
'This plugin has some known limitations. For Example, Pipeline Plugin is not fully supported.'.

But if you are using scripted pipelines you can implement something similar:

```
stage 'start up'
if(!env.testParam.matches('\\d+')) {
    error 'failure of parameter validation - does not match regex'
}
```

Comment: Thanks elworthy. This has given a good insight. I have used the extension point JobProperty to add new property for the job. And it worked for Freestyleproject and I am yet to test for pipelines. As you have pointed I will have to check if adding groovy prevents the build to happen if this property is not set.

Comment: @syk_coder glad to have helped. It would be good to either mark this as the answer, or add your own final code as an answer.

Comment: I have used used my plugin to extend JobProperty class and implement the build step this way I was able to add a new property put some validations and Fail the build when the validations failed. Thus making mandatory for people to give the details. It worked on Freestyle project, maven project, Multi config Projects. I am yet to explore on how this can be extended for Pipeline jobs. Thanks